# Delete Cookies from a Different Domain

Tags: c#, wpf, cookies, webautomation

I am working on a web automation tool.  After the tool is run once the associated website creates cookies that break the automation if I try to run it again.  Because of this I would like to delete the cookies before the automation starts.  I do not have access to the domain that actually creates the cookies.  Is this possible?  I know how to manipulate cookies, but all of that logic fails when you try to access cookies from a different website.

Additionally, I do not want to create a WebBrowser control if I can avoid it.  I am trying to do everything with httpWebRequests so that it looks nicer.

Comment: Most web automation tools (such as Selenium) provide support for modifying things like this.  What are you using as your tool?   (and no, you cannot do it directly through a web site as that would be a gross security violation)

Comment: I'm writing the automation tool in .NET 4.  I am not using a tool that already exists.

Comment: Because this automation will be a piece of other, much larger software and it needs to interface correctly.  I pull data from the software, and then will return the result at the end of the automation.

Comment: That the scope of your automation is large is actually an argument in *favor* of using an existing tool.

Comment: It looks like Selenium would need to be installed on the Client PC.  That is not an option.  From what I can tell I wouldn't be able to pack the automation within a .NET program.

Comment: ah, I understand now. I thought you were writing automation tests on your own site.

Comment: No.  It is actually rather strange.  The website doesn't require you to install plugins the first time you log in.  The second time it refuses to let you in without the plugins, and many of the client pc's will not allow them to install the plugins, so I have to work around that.  Do you know if it is possible to block plugins from being installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your test environment is running on a Windows system (and it sounds like it is) you can use pInvoke to manipulate the cache. The following four methods are needed. Unfortunately the code is owned by the company I work for, not me, so I can't paste it all here. It involves iterating over entries in the cache using "FindFirstUrlCacheEntry" and "FindNextUrlCacheEntry". Check the cache entry to see if it is a cookie and if it belongs to the domain you're interested in, if it is you can delete it.

```
[DllImport (@"wininet", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern IntPtr FindFirstUrlCacheEntry ([MarshalAs (UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] string searchPattern, IntPtr ptrCacheEntryInfo, ref int cacheEntryInfoSize);

[DllImport (@"wininet", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern bool FindNextUrlCacheEntry (IntPtr ptrCacheHandler, IntPtr ptrCacheEntryInfo, ref int cacheEntryInfoSize);

[DllImport (@"wininet", SetLastError = true, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern bool FindCloseUrlCache (IntPtr ptrCacheEntryInfo);

[DllImport ("wininet.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto, CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall)]
private static extern bool DeleteUrlCacheEntry (IntPtr lpszUrlName);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not be able to remove the cookie put by a website X using a http request comming from somewhere else than X.

You have 2 possibilities:

- You use the automatation tool to automate the removal of the cookie from the browser UI.
- You fake beeing the website X by changing the ip related to the x domain in your local cache (or by another mean).

Answer (score 0):

I ended up just clearing all the cookies.  There shouldn't be many the way that the server is set up, so it really will not be an issue.  Running through every cookie was the only way that it worked for me.  I get errors about my privilege level when I just try to delete the folder.

```
    private void ClearCookies()
    {
        string[] theCookies = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Cookies));

        foreach (string currentFile in theCookies)
        {
            try
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(currentFile);
            }
            catch (Exception ex) { }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yup, this seems like it will work for what you need. One thing I'd like to point out is that using the Windows SDK methods will include any cookies that are in memory, not just those that are written to files. In our specific case we are using a web browser control and need to delete some of its cookies while it might still be in memory.

Comment: That's an interesting point.  The cookies I need to clear should never been in memory when they are cleared, so it is a moot point, but I'll keep that in mind if I ever need to remove cookies in memory.